# Reverse proxy socket io server using nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I've been using docker and nginx for my microservice nest js apps with reverse proxy setup for each service so that I can access them under the different paths in the same port.

**Dockerfile** (identical for each service)

```
# Use a Node.js LTS version as the base image
FROM node:lts-alpine
# Create a working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./
# Install the dependencies
RUN npm install
# Copy the rest of the files to the working directory
COPY . .
# Expose the port 3000 so that the application can be accessed from outside the container
EXPOSE 3000
# Run the application
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

  upstream users {
    server user-api:3000;
  }

  upstream academic {
    server academic-api:3000;
  }
 
  server {
    listen 80;

    location /users/ {
      proxy_pass http://users/;
    }

    location /academic/ {
      proxy_pass http://academic/;
    }
  }
}
```

***docker-compose.yaml***

```
version: "3"

services:
  academic-api:
    container_name: academic-api
    image: academic-api
    build:
      context: ./academic-api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./academic-api:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm run start:dev
    restart: unless-stopped

  user-api:
    container_name: user-api
    image: user-api
    build:
      context: ./user-api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./user-api:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm run start:dev
    restart: unless-stopped

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - user-api
      - academic-api
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I can access my 2 services under http://localhost:3000/academic/ and http://localhost:3000/users/ and everything works fine.

Now I want to add websocket to the academic API and I am using socket io for this. By default the websocket server also starts up on port 3000 which is the http server port as well.

```
import { OnModuleInit } from "@nestjs/common";
import {
  ConnectedSocket,
  MessageBody,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
} from "@nestjs/websockets";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

@WebSocketGateway()
export class GatewayService implements OnModuleInit {
  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;

  onModuleInit() {
    console.log("GatewayService initialized");
    this.server.on("connection", (socket) => {
      console.log("Socket connected => " + socket.id);
    });
  }
}
```

But I can't get this to work on docker environment under nginx proxy. Basically, I want to be able to connect to the websocket if I hit http://localhost:3000/academic/ using websocket protocol using postman.

However, I am able to get this working if I run the academic api server locally on port 3000. When I use http protocol it connects to the http server, and if I use websocket protocol it connects to the websocket server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working by starting the WebSocket server on a different path and updating the Nginx conf and client handshake path.

```
@WebSocketGateway({ path: '/ws' })
export class GatewayService implements OnModuleInit {
...
}
```

```
server {
    listen 80;
...
    location /academic/ {
      proxy_pass http://academic/;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

and finally connect to the client with `http://localhost:3000/academic/ws/?EIO=4&transport=websocket`

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the nginx documentation please try using the following `nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

  upstream users {
    server user-api:3000;
  }

  upstream academic {
    server academic-api:3000;
  }
 
  server {
    listen 80;

    location /users/ {
      proxy_pass http://users/;
    }

    location /academic/ {
      proxy_pass http://academic/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

Comment: sorry not working. only thing that worked for me so far is

```
location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

      proxy_pass http://academic/;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

but I don't want to connect on root url, I want to connect on sub path like /academic

Comment: I dont really understand. If that is working, just put it in the location block with `location /academic` so it gets served by that uri.

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't work

Comment: Have you got any logs from the connecting client, why its not working?

Comment: Nothing useful, just displays a generic error like unable to connect